# All tests give same failed result but why?

Tags: javascript, angular, testing

I have created several components and services through Angular CLI. spec files are generated automagically.

When running my tests (56 of them) they all fail with the same message twice:

> Failed: Unexpected value '[object Object]' declared by the module
>   'DynamicTestModule'

I understand why it is twice because I have two beforeEach methods that get called. Removing one beforeEach also removes one of the errors. I hear you say: "Then remove both 'beforeEach' methods". Then my test will not run anymore.

I have now already spend 2 days looking at this and I'm totally out of ideas.

The only answer I could find touching this problem is that I need to import my routing file into the spec file. Done that but result is still the same.

Using a clean install of Angular 8.

I also tried using spy's to create the QueueComponent as it needs a QueueService in its constructor. Again, the same result.

One of the spec files looks like this:

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { QueuesComponent } from './queues.component';
import { faCheckCircle } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import { faTimesCircle } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import {Queue} from '../../objects/queue';
import {environment} from '../../../environments/environment';
import {AppRoutingModule} from './../../app-routing.module';

describe('QueuesComponent', () => {
  let component: QueuesComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<QueuesComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [faCheckCircle, faTimesCircle, Queue, environment ],
      imports: [AppRoutingModule]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(QueuesComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

The component belonging to this spec file is:

```
import {Component, OnDestroy, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {QueueService} from '../../services/queue.service';
import {Queue} from '../../objects/queue';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-queues',
  templateUrl: './queues.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./queues.component.css']
})
export class QueuesComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  failureQueues: Queue[];
  monitorQueues: Queue[];

  constructor(private queueService: QueueService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
  }
}
```

The HTML file is just showing a title in an  tag.

I would expect the test to run normal as I'm not doing anything fancy. In my opinion at least.

The complete error message is:

```
QueuesComponent > should create

Failed: Unexpected value '[object Object]' declared by the module 'DynamicTestModule'
error properties: Object({ ngSyntaxError: true })
Error: Unexpected value '[object Object]' declared by the module 'DynamicTestModule'
    at syntaxError (http://localhost:9877/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm2015/compiler.js:2175:1)
    at http://localhost:9877/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm2015/compiler.js:19694:1
    at <Jasmine>
    at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (http://localhost:9877/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm2015/compiler.js:19692:1)
    at JitCompiler._loadModules (http://localhost:9877/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm2015/compiler.js:25402:1)
    at JitCompiler._compileModuleAndAllComponents (http://localhost:9877/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm2015/compiler.js:25391:1)
    at JitCompiler.compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync (http://localhost:9877/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm2015/compiler.js:25353:1)
    at CompilerImpl.compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync (http://localhost:9877/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/fesm2015/platform-browser-dynamic.js:237:1)
    at TestingCompilerImpl.compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync (http://localhost:9877/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/fesm2015/testing.js:140:1)
    at TestBedViewEngine.compileComponents (http://localhost:9877/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/testing.js:3086:1)


Error: Unexpected value '[object Object]' declared by the module 'DynamicTestModule'
error properties: Object({ ngSyntaxError: true })
Error: Unexpected value '[object Object]' declared by the module 'DynamicTestModule'
    at syntaxError (http://localhost:9877/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm2015/compiler.js:2175:1)
    at http://localhost:9877/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm2015/compiler.js:19694:1
    at <Jasmine>
    at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (http://localhost:9877/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm2015/compiler.js:19692:1)
    at JitCompiler._loadModules (http://localhost:9877/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm2015/compiler.js:25402:1)
    at JitCompiler._compileModuleAndAllComponents (http://localhost:9877/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm2015/compiler.js:25391:1)
    at JitCompiler.compileModuleAndAllComponentsSync (http://localhost:9877/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm2015/compiler.js:25350:1)
    at CompilerImpl.compileModuleAndAllComponentsSync (http://localhost:9877/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/fesm2015/platform-browser-dynamic.js:225:1)
    at TestingCompilerImpl.compileModuleAndAllComponentsSync (http://localhost:9877/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/fesm2015/testing.js:132:1)
    at TestBedViewEngine._initIfNeeded (http://localhost:9877/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/testing.js:3108:1)


Expected undefined to be truthy.
Error: Expected undefined to be truthy.
    at <Jasmine>
    at UserContext.<anonymous> (http://localhost:9877/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/src/app/components/queues/queues.component.spec.ts:29:23)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:9877/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-evergreen.js:359:1)
    at ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke (http://localhost:9877/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js:308:1)
```

Comment: What *are* those things in the declarations array?

Comment: Next to the question why there is the environment and fontawesome icons inside the declaration what is your intention with importing the app's routing module inside your component? What are you trying to achieve with that?

Comment: In the HTML page I had some icons from FontAwesome that needed to be included otherwise I would get other errors as well. Once I changed the page to a title only I should have removed these fa... items. Queue and environment are objects I use in the QueueComponent. After stripping the component down to its bare minimum I could have removed the environment declaration.  removing them and running the test again... same result

Comment: Importing the app's routing was the result of an answer I found for a question that looked the same as my problem.

Comment: Well one thing is that the environment should not be inside your declarations. You can use that in your test without that since those are global variables. The other thing with your fontawesome icons is that you don't need to declare those if they don't interest you inside your test. But that could be done later. The app routing module should not be included inside this component test unless your component uses the app routing module (which it should not do). What you are missing is a stub for the service test, if the service is used inside the constructor or the onInit method.

Comment: And you should not declare the Queue object as well since it seems only to be a type you are using? Please remove all the unnecessary declarations and post the error you are getting afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

As Erbsenkoenig suggested I removed all unnecessary code and created a stub for the QueueService (Which in turn uses an HttpClient).

```
import {async, ComponentFixture, getTestBed, TestBed} from '@angular/core/testing';

import { QueuesComponent } from './queues.component';
import {QueueService} from '../../services/queue.service';
import {HttpClientTestingModule} from '@angular/common/http/testing';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
import {CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA} from '@angular/core';

const dummyQueues = [
  {value: 33, name: 'MDM03', max: 300},
  {value: 0, name: 'MDM99', max: 200}
];

class StubQueueService {
  getFailureQueues() {
    return Observable.of(dummyQueues);
  }
  getMonitorQueues() {
    return Observable.of(dummyQueues);
  }
}

describe('QueuesComponent', () => {
  let component: QueuesComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<QueuesComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    let injector;
    let queuesService: QueueService;

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ QueuesComponent ],
      imports: [ HttpClientTestingModule ],
      providers: [
        {provide: QueueService, useClass: StubQueueService}
      ],
      schemas: [ CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA ]
    }).compileComponents();

    injector = getTestBed();
    queuesService = injector.get(QueueService);
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(QueuesComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Comment: Your component should use a test double for the *service*, not the real service with a test double of the service's collaborator. Also Angular provides for testing use of the HttpClientModule in the... HttpClient*Testing*Module; you don't need to roll your own.

Comment: jonrsharpe: Is this a better solution?

Comment: Yes, that's definitely an improvement. Your test double of the queue service is properly a *stub*, as you describe it above the code, not a *fake* as it's named (see e.g. http://engineering.pivotal.io/post/the-test-double-rule-of-thumb/). Now you just need some useful test cases!

Comment: Thanks for the comment although it caused me some headaches as I'm fairly new to this kind of testing. Learned something new so that's a good thing.